# Login details remains after user logout swift using Token authentication

Tags: swift, django-rest-auth

I have an application that uses rest framework to provide API. I have the application all setup but I have a challenge in that when a user login the user's details is gotten. login is achieved via token authentication and this is stored in `UserDefaults` when the logout button is clicked the user details is removed from the device and login in with another user is supposed to be displayed on login i.e the logged in user,s email and username but instead it shows the initial logged in user,s details and no matter how much I try it it never displays the current logged in users details but instead it displays the initial users details.

My login code is

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

var isLoggedIn : Bool {

    get {
        return defaults.bool(forKey: LOGGED_IN_KEY)
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: LOGGED_IN_KEY)
    }
}

var authToken: String {
    get {
        return defaults.value(forKey: TOKEN_KEY) as? String ?? ""
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: TOKEN_KEY)
    }
}

var userUsername: String {
    get {
        return defaults.value(forKey: USER_USERNAME) as? String ?? ""
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: USER_USERNAME)
    }
}
//MARK :- LOGGIN
func findUserByUserName(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_BY_USERNAME, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: TOKEN_HEADER).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        print("URL USER BY HEADER \(self.authToken)")

        if response.result.error == nil {

            guard let data = response.data else {return}
            let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print(jsonString as Any)
            self.setUserInfo(data: data)

            completion(true)
            }
         else {


            completion(false)
            debugPrint("ERROR 22222\(response.result.error as Any)")
        }
    }
}


func setUserInfo(data: Data) -> Void {
    do {
        let json = try JSON(data: data)
        let pk = json["pk"].intValue
        let username = json["username"].stringValue
        let email = json["email"].stringValue
        let firstName = json["first_name"].stringValue
        let lastName = json["last_nameme"].stringValue

        print("THE USERNAME IZZZZ \(username)")

        UserDataService.instance.setUserData(pk: pk, username: username, email: email, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

UserDetails

```
class UserDataService {

    static let instance = UserDataService()

    public private(set) var pk = 0
    public private(set) var username = ""
    public private(set) var email = ""
    public private(set) var firstName = ""
    public private(set) var lastName = ""


    func setUserData(pk: Int, username: String, email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String) -> Void {

        self.pk = pk
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }


    func logoutUser() -> Void {
        self.pk = 0
        self.username = ""
        self.email = ""
        self.firstName = ""
        self.lastName = ""
        AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn = false
        AuthService.instance.authToken = ""
        AuthService.instance.userUsername = ""
    }}
```

For my logout I have

```
@IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDataService.instance.logoutUser()
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NOTIFY_USER_DATA_DID_CHANGE, object: nil)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Part of login**
    func setupUserInfo() {

```
        if AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn {
            loginBtn.setTitle(UserDataService.instance.username, for: .normal)

        } else {
            loginBtn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
            userImg.image = UIImage(named: "menuProfileIcon")
            userImg.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance and further codes would be supplied on request

Comment: You're not showing the code that displays the user info on the screen. Did you check to see if the second user info is coming back after calling findUserByEmail? Trace it from there and work your way to the UI.

Comment: The user's details is not coming back

Comment: Then that's your problem. Make sure you're using the second user's email address.

Comment: but for the initial login, the user's details is gotten and on logout I clear the details that were supplied by the previous user. So I dont know why the same logic is not working

Comment: You have Alamofire.request that uses an email address to get the user info. Which variable has this email address? I can't tell by the code. The problem looks to be in the Alamofire request, not in your local user info.

Comment: it is username that it uses and the username is the user that inputs his details in the text field and correct password

Comment: You mean this variable: URL_USER_BY_USERNAME? Make sure you're updating it to reflect the new user.

Comment: I don’t know how to achieve that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172111/discussion-between-u84six-and-king).